# Oracle - Group-level summaries

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, aggregation, group-summaries

I am trying to create a report that has a summary for each group. For example:

```
ID           NAME              COUNT           TOTAL     TYPE
-------------------------------------------------------------
1            Test 1            10                         A
2            Test 2            8                          A
                                               18

7            Mr. Test          9                          B
12           XYZ               4                          B
                                               13

25           ABC               3                          C
26           DEF               5                          C
19           GHIJK             1                          C
                                               9
```

I have a query that can do everything except the TOTAL columns:

```
       select sd.id DATA_REF_NUM ID, count(sd.DATA_DEF_ID) COUNT, defs.data_name NAME, sd.type
       from some_data sd, data_defs defs
       where sd.data_def_id = defs.data_def_id
       group by some_data.type, some_data.id, defs.data_nam
       order by some_data.id asc, count(amv.MSG_ID) desc ;
```

I'm just not sure how to get a summary on a group. In this case, I'm trying to get a sum of COUNT for each group of ID.

**UPDATE:**

Groups are by type. Forgot that in the original post.

TOTAL is SUM(COUNT) for each group.

Comment: How are you grouping things to get your TOTAL column? I don't see anything in your query that groups ID 1 and 2 together. IOW, why are ID's 1 and 2 in one group, and 7 and 12 in another? Is there another column in your data that does that for you?

Comment: @DCookie: Whoops, yeah I grouping for SUM(COUNT) should be by TYPE, not ID, Updated to show that.

Comment: Is this to be done in SQL*Plus?

Comment: @DCookie: probably. Right now I'm working in PL/SQL Developer, I want to be able to have these reports generated and exported at the click of a button. Everthing to do that is already in place - except the query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using ROLLUP like...

`select sd.id DATA_REF_NUM ID, count(sd.DATA_DEF_ID) COUNT, defs.data_name NAME, sd.type
       from some_data sd, data_defs defs
       where sd.data_def_id = defs.data_def_id
       group by ROLLUP(some_data.type, (some_data.id, defs.data_nam))
       order by some_data.id asc, count(amv.MSG_ID) desc ;`

This works for a similar example in my database, but I only did it over two columns, not sure how it will function over more...
Hope this is helpful,
Craig...

EDIT:  In a ROLLUP, columns you want to sum over but not subtotal over like id and data_nam should be lumped together inside the ROLLUP in parantheses)

Comment: Hehehe... perfect timing! I just discovered ROLLUP about 15 mintues ago... A little tweaking but I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL*Plus, you could do something like this:

```
col d1 noprint
col d2 noprint
WITH q AS
(SELECT sd.id, count(sd.DATA_DEF_ID) COUNT, defs.data_name NAME, sd.type
   FROM some_data sd JOIN data_defs defs ON (sd.data_def_id = defs.data_def_id)
  GROUP BY some_data.type, some_data.id, defs.data_nam)
SELECT 1 d1, type d2, id, count, name FROM q
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, type, null, null, null, SUM(count) FROM q GROUP BY 2, type
 ORDER BY 2,1,3;
```

I can't make this work in PL/SQL Developer 8, only SQL*Plus.  Not even the command window will work...

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery that returns the count of all the items of the type.  This would

```
select sd.id DATA_REF_NUM ID, count(sd.DATA_DEF_ID) COUNT, tot.TOTAL_FOR_TYPE, defs.data_name NAME, sd.type
   from some_data sd, data_defs defs, 
      (select count(sd2.DATA_DEF_ID) TOTAL_FOR_TYPE 
       from some_data sd2
       where sd2.type = sd.type) tot
   where sd.data_def_id = defs.data_def_id
   group by some_data.type, some_data.id, defs.data_nam
   order by some_data.id asc, count(amv.MSG_ID) desc ;
```